# Android studio 2.0 and "Performing VCS refresh.."

Tags: android-studio, svn, version-control

Moved my Android projects from Eclipse to Android Studio 2.0 today.. Was surprised when couldn't commit new projects into SVN we use for Eclipse. Android Studio just wasn't able to finish "Performing VCS refresh" operation during probably 2 hours.. It's really disappointing.. 
Has anybody solved this problem? not for Intellij but for Android Studio? 
Yea.. I know, I'll try to commit from command line, then check it out, then.. 
Or I'll switch my repository to Git but all these are "last chance" solutions.